# svn: do we need a test branch

Tags: svn, branch

I am trying to migrate my project to SVN. in my previous projects we used to have Trunk as the dev area where the developer used to check out and commit to (unless there is a branch for a special release). Then we used to have a branch for Test area.

Looking at SVN now i dont see the need for a test branch, we can make a build upon the Dev trunk and most examples i am getting dont even mention a Test branch specifically.

In my previous companies and projects, the test branches were there because we had different configurations for test servers so the config.xml files were different for each environment so we ahd different branches for each environemnt.

Can any one help me how to tackle this issue. do we need to have a Test branch just cos of different config files or hwo do people Test?

Comment: Just thinking: is it a good idea instead to have multiple trunks (for Prod, Test, QA)???

Answer (score 2):

Branches are useful if two versions of the code base are evolving independently, for example if you want to do bug fixing of the released version but at the same time also continue with development.

If you just have a test version, a tag would be sufficient most of the time. (Technically tags and branches are the same in subversion, but there is a semantic difference).

Comment: Thanks, then how do developers maintain an environemnt where the xml config files like spring-config.xml, web.xml, ant build files,  are different for different environments.

Comment: One could do that with branches but its often much easier to just keep them on the same branch in different directories or with different file names. You can either copy them to the right place (depending on environment) during the build or make the application smart enough to pick them up at the right directory (for example pass in the environment as a system property).

Comment: Thanks. I have done this before and named my xmls or build files to be prefixed or postfixed with ENV names. they worked fine as well.